# Can a partial number of columns in a CSV file be imported to Solr using post.jar?

Tags: csv, solr, schema, unique-key, solrconfig

I'm trying to only import certain columns of a `CSV` file into Solr, but I'm not sure how to do this or if this is even possible with Solr. Currently, I'm using one of the `books.csv` examples that came with the Solr installation (can be found in **C:\solr-5.2.1\example\exampledocs**).

The below `xml` that I put in the `schema.xml` file works if all fields are included, but if I comment some fields out, Solr complains about unknown fields that are the ones commented out.

```
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>

<!-- Fields added for books.csv load-->
<field name="cat" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="price" type="tdouble" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

<!-- these columns commented out
<field name="inStock" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="author" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
-->
```

Because the post script in **C:\solr-5.2.1\bin** is a `shell` script and wont run in Windows, which I am using, I need to use the `post.jar` file located in the same place as the `books.csv` file.

```
java -Dtype=text/csv -Durl=http://localhost:8983/solr/jcg/update -jar post.jar books.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

CSV Update Handler has [a large number of parameters](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Index+Handlers#UploadingDatawithIndexHandlers-CSVFormattedIndexUpdates) to control CSV import process. **skip** seems the most relevant to your specific problem.